# grid unique paths - recursion

Tags: recursion, path, grid

I am trying to solve the grid unique paths problem. The problem involves finding the number of possible unique paths in a 2D grid starting from top left (0,0) to the bottom right (say A,B). One can only move right or down. Here is my initial attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count=0;
void uniquePathsRecur(int r, int c, int A, int B){
    if(r==A-1 & c==B-1){
        count++;
        return;
    }
    if(r<A-1){
        return uniquePathsRecur(r++,c,A,B);
    }
    if(c<B-1){
        return uniquePathsRecur(r,c++,A,B);
    }

}

int uniquePaths(int A, int B) {

    if(B==1 | A==1){
        return 1;
    }

    uniquePathsRecur(0,0,A,B);
    return count;
}


int main(){

printf("%d", uniquePaths(5,3));

return 0;
}
```

I end up getting segmentation fault: 11 with my code. I tried to debug in gdb and i get the following:

```
lldb) target create "a.out"
Current executable set to 'a.out' (x86_64).
(lldb) r
Process 12171 launched: '<path to process>/a.out' (x86_64)
Process 12171 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x531b2e, 0x0000000100000e38 a.out`uniquePathsRecur + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff5f3ffffc)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000e38 a.out`uniquePathsRecur + 8
a.out`uniquePathsRecur:
->  0x100000e38 <+8>:  movl   %edi, -0x4(%rbp)
    0x100000e3b <+11>: movl   %esi, -0x8(%rbp)
    0x100000e3e <+14>: movl   %edx, -0xc(%rbp)
    0x100000e41 <+17>: movl   %ecx, -0x10(%rbp)
(lldb)
```

What is wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the problem of your code. But you can solve the problem without using recursion.

> Method 1: We can solve this problem with simple math skill. The
>   requirement is that you can only move either down or right at any
>   point. So it requires exact (m + n) steps from S to D and n out of (m
>   + n) steps go down. Thus, the answer is C(m + n, n).
>
> Method 2: Let us solve the issue in computer science way. This is a typical dynamic
>   programming problem. Let us assume the robot is standing at (i, j).
>   How did the robot arrive at (i, j)? The robot could move down from (i
>   - 1, j) or move right from (i, j - 1). So the path to (i, j) is equal to the sum of path to (i - 1, j) and path to (i, j - 1). We can use
>   another array to store the path to all node and use the equation
>   below: paths(i, j) = 1 // i == 0 or j == 0 paths(i, j) = paths(i - 1,
>   j) + paths(i, j - 1) // i != 0 and j != 0 However, given more
>   thoughts, you will find out that you don't actually need a 2D array to
>   record all the values since when the robot is at row i, you only need
>   the paths at (i - 1). So the equation is: paths(j) = 1 //j == 0 for
>   any i paths(j) = paths(j - 1) + paths(j) // j != 0 for any i

For more information, please see here: https://algorithm.pingzhang.io/DynamicProgramming/unique_path.html